# OpenScenario: Where to find the catalogs?

Tags: xml, carla

I am using openscenario to write some scenarios for Carla. 
Where to find these scenarios? In the header of the XML files, there are some catalogs defined.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OpenSCENARIO>
    <FileHeader revMajor="0" revMinor="9" date="2019-06-25" description="CyclistCrossing" author="" />
    <Catalogs>
        <PedestrianCatalog>
            <Directory path="Catalogs/ObserverCatalogs" />
        </PedestrianCatalog>
        <PedestrianControllerCatalog>
            <Directory path="Catalogs/PedestrianCatalogs" />
        </PedestrianControllerCatalog>
    </Catalogs>
```

I just want to let to spawn a pedestrian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so there's an answer on this - scenariorunner does not currently support Catalogs.